# is MKMapView allocating its own location manager?

Tags: iphone, sdk, mapkit

I'm not understanding if a MKMApView has its own Location Manager. From one side there is not any delegate method to handle the updating of position and so on. From the other side I can set to show userLocation and thus there must be a Location Manager allocated. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

yes it does. I have no proof of this but it is logically obvious. I think you answered that yourself :-)